# validate capcha zend not correct

Tags: zend-framework

I have code:

```
 $messages = array();
 $isValid = TRUE;
 $captcha = $this->_getParam('captcha_code', '');
 if ( ! Captcha::validate($captcha)){
     $isValid = FALSE;
     $messages = array_merge($messages, array('Incorrect capcha.'));
 }
                }
 if ($isValid AND count($messages) == 0) {
        .............
 }
 else {
       Captcha::destroy();
 }
 $this->view->register_messages = $messages;
```

and view:

```
<input name="captcha_code" type="text" class="input-text"/>
<?php if (isset($this->register_messages) && count($this->register_messages) > 0): ?>
<div class="alert-3">
<?php foreach ($this->register_messages as $message): ?>
<div><?= $message ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But when i enter correct capcha, it still showing "Incorrect capcha". I use zend 1
Please help me find this bug. Thanks a lot!